# How to fix bug with Chrome not using cached videos on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser-cache

I have a site that needs to load and play videos (about 5MB total) from cache. Chrome on my laptop will cache the videos, and the next page load it will play the videos from cache. On my Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 Chrome V 47 will cache the videos (I see that the cache for my page is 5MB), but on the next page load it will still try retrieving them from the server.

Here is my cache.manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2015-12-07:v1.0.0

CACHE:
video1.mp4
video2.mp4

NETWORK:
*
```

And my index.html file includes the cache file:

```
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
```

Am I missing something to make caching videos work on my Nexus, or is there another way to cache videos on a Nexus in Chrome?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The Media stack on Desktop and Mobile are two different stacks and they are not yet shared.  The reason why you are seeing this issue is that all requests for Media (Audio and Video) are not sent through Chrome's network stack, but rather they are sent through Android's Media stack and network stack.  This has the unfortunate consequence of by-passing the AppCache.

Hopefully this will be rectified in the future.  [Track this bug for status updates](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=547613)